# Elasticsearch combining fuzzy matching with geo distance sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch query which includes a bool must match query as well as a geo distance sort. I'm allowing a fuzziness level of 1 on the match. The issue I'm running into is that the sort causes the matched document scores to be disregarded and thus there is the potential for several fuzzy matches to appear in the results list before an exact match if the fuzzy matches were geographically closer to the search location.

Is there a way to combine fuzzy matching with geo distance sorting, such that exact matches still take precedence over fuzzy matches which were closer in distance? Or - am I thinking about this the wrong way, and do I need to take a different approach?

Another option I had considered is to perform multiple queries in different search radius bands using a geo distance filter (5, 10, 25 miles etc) *without* the distance sorting, and combining the results. I'd like to avoid multiple queries if possible though as this is all for a typeahead feature and performance is crucial.

Currently my query looks something like:

```
GET <myindex>/_search
{
  "from": 0, "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "searchName": {
              "query" : "my query",
              "operator" : "AND",
              "fuzziness" : "1",
              "fuzzy_transpositions" : true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance" : {
          "location" : [-93.26000213623047, 44.970001220703125],
          "order" : "asc",
          "unit" : "mi",
          "mode" : "min",
          "distance_type" : "arc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to you to sort by `_geo_distance` **and** `_score`, with `_score` sort coming first.

```
"sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "_geo_distance" : {
          "location" : [-93.26000213623047, 44.970001220703125],
          "order" : "asc",
          "unit" : "mi",
          "mode" : "min",
          "distance_type" : "arc"
      }
    }
  ]
```

In this case, you would first sort by matching, which would make exact match to appear higher, while then for same score you will sort on distance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your example, would the `_geo_distance` sort _only_ happen as a tiebreaker for documents with the exact same match `_score`?

Comment: Yes, that what exactly would happen, which would makes exactly as you want, right? you will get results for "my query" and then properly will sort them by distance